# Left join on two tables and want to get results from a specific date

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, wordpress

I have written a MySQL query to do left join on two tables .

My result query is showing the result I wanted . I just want to know how to further make it limited to specific dates .

The column which I want to sort is user_registered and is showing date in this format 2020-12-17 06:06:05. So how to make it from two different dates . This is my query which I have written down .

```
SELECT wp_users.user_email,user_nicename,user_registered,freelancerpaid
FROM wp_users
LEFT JOIN wp_posts
ON wp_users.ID = wp_posts.post_author
WHERE wp_posts.post_type="freelancers"
AND wp_users.freelancerpaid="1"
```

[These are the results i am getting from the query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oLlZJ.png) 
So what I want is to get results from the specific dates I can enter .

Thanks in advance .

Comment: you can use like for specific date in where clause `WHERE user_registered LIKE '%2020-12-17%'`

Comment: But Akshay it will only give me for that specific date like how to make it like any date less than it or greater than it thanks .

Comment: `WHERE DATE(user_registered) <= '2020-12-17'` for `less or equal` or use `>= `for `greater or equal`

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: And why 'LEFT' join?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you neet to get **Between two dates**, use this.

```
SELECT wp_users.user_email,user_nicename,user_registered,freelancerpaid
FROM wp_users
LEFT JOIN wp_posts
ON wp_users.ID = wp_posts.post_author
WHERE wp_posts.post_type="freelancers"
AND wp_users.freelancerpaid="1"
AND DATE(user_registered) BETWEEN '2020-11-28' AND '2020-11-29'
```

But if you neet to get **lesser or greater than the date**, use this. Just change the condition base on what you need.

```
SELECT wp_users.user_email,user_nicename,user_registered,freelancerpaid
FROM wp_users
LEFT JOIN wp_posts
ON wp_users.ID = wp_posts.post_author
WHERE wp_posts.post_type="freelancers"
AND wp_users.freelancerpaid="1"
AND DATE(user_registered) >= '2020-11-29'
```

Comment: This is an INNER JOIN, as demonstrated by executing EXPLAIN EXTENDED [your query] followed by SHOW WARNINGS

Comment: Also, note that functions cannot use indexes (in the event that an index is provided)

Comment: @SyedFaseehUlHassan if the answer solved your problem, how about marking Pauls answer as a solution and give him credits?

Answer (score 1):

**Stop**, your query is not doing what you want.

It is not doing `Left join` but it is doing `inner join`.

If you really want the `left join` then condition on left joined table must be in the `ON` clause and where condition on `wp_users` can go in `where` clause as follows:

```
SELECT wp_users.user_email,user_nicename,user_registered,freelancerpaid
  FROM wp_users
  LEFT JOIN wp_posts ON wp_users.ID = wp_posts.post_author
                    And wp_posts.post_type="freelancers" -- this is moved to ON clause
 Where wp_users.freelancerpaid="1"
   And DATE(wp_users.user_registered) BETWEEN '2020-11-28' AND '2020-11-29'
```